# D3.js: Update barplot based on variable input

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3.js and I'm having a little trouble understanding how I can filter the graph out based on a HTML input. My CSV is as follows:

```
word3,value,channel,person
focused,2,cnnnews18,modi
hailed,2,cnnnews18,modi
improved,2,cnnnews18,modi
wins,4,ndtv,modi
welcomed,2,ndtv,modi
praise,3,republic,modi
celebrates,3,republic,modi
```

Since I wanted to filter this by the variable `channel`, I wrote the following function after I had read in my CSV:

```js
// Filter by 'cnn', for example
data = data.filter (function(d){ 
            return d.channel== "cnn"; 
});
```

But I would like this filtering to be done by the user instead of me. So I've set up buttons with ids that contain the channel names are variables. HTML:

```
 <div id="my_dataviz"> 
         <button id="republic">Republic</button>
         <button id="ndtv">NDTV</button></div>
      </div>
```

And the part that reads in the button IDs:

```js
   d3.selectAll("button").on("click", function(){
        draw(this.id);
      });
```

`draw(this.id);` executes the draw function , which contains information about how to draw the graph. Now my understanding is that I would wrap the entire part of the code where the data is being read and the graph being drawn within `draw(channel)`, where `channel` would depend on which button was clicked. This is the code I now have:

```js
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
      width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0,width]);

    var y = d3.scaleBand()
        .rangeRound([height,0])
        .padding(0.2);

    d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thedivtagguy/files/main/sent_modi.csv",types,function(error,data){

      if (error) throw error;

      data.sort(function(a,b){
        return b.value - a.value;
      });

      d3.selectAll("button").on("click", function(){
        draw(this.id);
      });

      draw("ndtv");

      function draw(myChannel){

        data = data.filter(function(d){ return d.channel== myChannel; 
    })
     

      
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ return d.value; }));
      y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.word3; }));
      

      svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d){ return d.value < 0 ? x(d.value) : x(0); })
                      .attr("width", function(d){ return d.value < 0 ? x(d.value * -1) - x(0) : x(d.value) - x(0); })
          .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.word3); })
                      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
                      .attr("fill", function(d){ return d.value < 0 ? "#d7191c": "#1a9641"; });

              svg.selectAll(".value")
                      .data(data)
                  .enter().append("text")
                      .attr("class", "value")
                      .attr("x", function(d){
                          if (d.value < 0){
                              return (x(d.value * -1) - x(0)) > 20 ? x(d.value) + 2 : x(d.value) - 1;
                          } else {
                              return (x(d.value) - x(0)) > 20 ? x(d.value) - 2 : x(d.value) + 1;
                          }
                      })
                      .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.word3); })
                      .attr("dy", y.bandwidth() - 2.55)
                      .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
                          if (d.value < 0){
                              return (x(d.value * -1) - x(0)) > 20 ? "start" : "end";
                          } else {
                              return (x(d.value) - x(0)) > 20 ? "end" : "start";
                          }
                      })
                      .style("fill", function(d){
                          if (d.value < 0){
                              return (x(d.value * -1) - x(0)) > 20 ? "#fff" : "#3a403d";
                          } else {
                              return (x(d.value) - x(0)) > 20 ? "#fff" : "#3a403d";
                          }
                      })
                      .text(function(d){ return d.value; });

              svg.selectAll(".name")
                      .data(data)
                  .enter().append("text")
                      .attr("class", "name")
                      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.value < 0 ? x(0) + 2.55 : x(0) - 2.55 })
                      .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.word3); })
                      .attr("dy", y.bandwidth() - 2.55)
                      .attr("text-anchor", function(d){ return d.value < 0 ? "start" : "end"; })
                      .text(function(d){ return d.word3; });

              svg.append("line")
                      .attr("x1", x(0))
                      .attr("x2", x(0))
                      .attr("y1", 0 + margin.top)
                      .attr("y2", height - margin.top)
                      .attr("stroke", "#3a403d")
                      .attr("stroke-width", "1px");
                    }

     bars.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("width", 0)
    .remove();
    

    });

    function types(d){
              d.value = +d.value;
              return d;
    }
```

I call `draw("ndtv)` to draw the first graph. This isn't changing anything though, what am I doing wrong? It would help if the answer can also explain how to generalize such update functions, since I would like to not only solve it for this graph but apply it to any other.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o2w17Lxf/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some errors in scope, enter/exit pattern and data handling. See it's fixed in the snippet:

```js
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
      width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0,width]);

    var y = d3.scaleBand()
        .rangeRound([height,0])
        .padding(0.2);

    d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thedivtagguy/files/main/sent_modi.csv",types,function(error,fullData){
  console.log('FULLDATA: ', fullData);

      if (error) throw error;

    const sortedData = fullData.sort(function(a,b){
        return b.value - a.value;
      }).map((d, i) => ({...d, id: i}));

      d3.selectAll("button").on("click", function(){
        console.log('C: ', this.id)
        draw(this.id);
      });

      draw("cnnnews18");

      function draw(myRegion){

        const data = sortedData.filter(function(d){ return d.channel== myRegion; 
    })
       console.log('DATA: ', data);

      
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ return d.value; }));
      y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.word3; }));
      

      const bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data, d => d.id)
        bars.enter()
      .append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d){ return d.value < 0 ? x(d.value) : x(0); })
            .attr("width", function(d){ return d.value < 0 ? x(d.value * -1) - x(0) : x(d.value) - x(0); })
          .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.word3); })
            .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
            .attr("fill", function(d){ return d.value < 0 ? "#d7191c": "#1a9641"; });

     const values = svg.selectAll(".value")
       .data(data, d => d.id);
     
  values.enter().append("text")
         .attr("class", "value")
         .attr("x", function(d){
          if (d.value < 0){
              return (x(d.value * -1) - x(0)) > 20 ? x(d.value) + 2 : x(d.value) - 1;
              } else {
              return (x(d.value) - x(0)) > 20 ? x(d.value) - 2 : x(d.value) + 1;
                }
         })
         .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.word3); })
         .attr("dy", y.bandwidth() - 2.55)
         .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
                          if (d.value < 0){
                              return (x(d.value * -1) - x(0)) > 20 ? "start" : "end";
                          } else {
                              return (x(d.value) - x(0)) > 20 ? "end" : "start";
                          }
                      })
         .style("fill", function(d){
                          if (d.value < 0){
                              return (x(d.value * -1) - x(0)) > 20 ? "#fff" : "#3a403d";
                          } else {
                              return (x(d.value) - x(0)) > 20 ? "#fff" : "#3a403d";
                          }
                      })
         .text(function(d){ return d.value; });
     values.exit().remove();

            const names = svg.selectAll(".name")
              .data(data, d => d.id)
        
            names.enter().append("text")
              .attr("class", "name")
              .attr("x", function(d){ return d.value < 0 ? x(0) + 2.55 : x(0) - 2.55 })
              .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.word3); })
              .attr("dy", y.bandwidth() - 2.55)
              .attr("text-anchor", function(d){ return d.value < 0 ? "start" : "end"; })
              .text(function(d){ return d.word3; });
        names.exit().remove();

            svg.selectAll('.zero-line').remove();
            svg.append("line")
        .classed('zero-line', true)
              .attr("x1", x(0))
              .attr("x2", x(0))
              .attr("y1", 0 + margin.top)
              .attr("y2", height - margin.top)
              .attr("stroke", "#3a403d")
              .attr("stroke-width", "1px");
      
     bars.exit()
     /*
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("width", 0)
  */
    .remove();


    }
  });

    function types(d){
              d.value = +d.value;
              return d;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>


      <div id="my_dataviz"> 
         <button id="republic">Republic</button>
         <button id="ndtv">NDTV</button>
      <button id="cnnnews18">CNN</button>   
         
         </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you so much! I'll be taking notes by comparing the differences and seeing where I went wrong.